# iCloud unlock with new Apple ID's password

Tags: icloud, activation-lock

I have a iPhone 5s which is iCloud locked. I know the Apple ID's email but I don't know the Apple ID's password. I can access to the email which is the Apple ID's email. I want to reset the Apple ID's password and then enter my email and password to the iPhone.

If I reset my Apple ID's password and then enter email and **new** password on my iPhone, will it unlock?

I think the answer is **yes** because when I turn on iPhone it will require a Wi-Fi network. And when I will enter my Apple ID to the phone it will check my login information with Apple servers.  Am I true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the login will authenticate with Apple's servers to verify the password, ensuring it is verifying the latest possible password, hence the network requirement.